# Bootstrap 5 - hide modal does not remove backdrop

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5 I create my modal:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('scheduleMeetingModal'), {
    backdrop: 'static'
});
myModal.show();
```

On another function I want to hide that modal, and use:

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
```

However the backdrop stays there. I'm not able to change the passed options to remove backdrop and can't find anything on the Bootstrap documentation.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
myModal.modal({backdrop: false});
```

EDIT:
As requested, the html code for my modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="scheduleMeetingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="scheduleMeetingModalLabel"><?php echo lang('App.scheduleMeeting'); ?></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('schedule_meeting', 'id="schedule_meeting" class="needs-validation" novalidate=""'); ?>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3 feature-info-content">
                                <label class="form-label" for="day_one"><?php echo lang('App.day'); ?> *</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="day_one" required name="day_one">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3 feature-info-content">
                                <label class="form-label" for="time_one"><?php echo lang('App.startTime'); ?> *</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="time" id="time_one" required name="time_one">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="schedule_meeting" class="btn btn-primary ms-5"><?php echo lang('App.submit'); ?></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show me your HTML code...

Comment: regular modal with a form inside which submits with success. Not sure how the html can help but I will add to my question

Comment: Thanks for the code. let me add some code in my answer you can try and let me know if that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer made me realize that the modal instance was not being properly retrieve, so according to the Bootstrap 5 documentation you can set or retrieve an existing instance of the modal object.

So I changed my code as follows and it worked

```
var myModalEl = document.querySelector('#scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
```

This hides the backdrop properly and does not involve changing my code any further nor declaring the modal instance globally.

Comment: didn't work for me ,bootstrap 5.1.3 without Jquery

Comment: Same. Did not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myModalEl = document.querySelector('#scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
```

This solution not work for me, I add :

```
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
```

to remove backdrop and it works.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? This particular problem was with bootstrap 5

Comment: yes, I use bootstrap 5.

Comment: When I tried this, it also removed the page slider, so not sure how to get that to not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended your code. Your javascript code was invalid that why its not working properly. Now I have fixed the issue. You can run this code and check it.

```js
var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(
  document.getElementById("scheduleMeetingModal")
);

function openModal() {
  modal.show();
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.hide();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->


<div class="modal" id="scheduleMeetingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="scheduleMeetingModalLabel"><?php echo lang('App.scheduleMeeting'); ?></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeModal()"></button>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('schedule_meeting', 'id="schedule_meeting" class="needs-validation" novalidate=""'); ?>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3 feature-info-content">
                                <label class="form-label" for="day_one">
                                    <?php echo lang('App.day'); ?> *</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="day_one" required name="day_one"> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3 feature-info-content">
                                <label class="form-label" for="time_one">
                                    <?php echo lang('App.startTime'); ?> *</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="time" id="time_one" required name="time_one"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" id="schedule_meeting" class="btn btn-primary ms-5">
                        <?php echo lang('App.submit'); ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: but why is my javascript invalid? because the modal was not declared globally?

Comment: The question specifically mentioned bootstrap 5, yet your answer includes bootstrap 4.4

Comment: Hello @AndrewMellor, On bootstrap 4.4 and 5.0 the method is same. it should work fine.